# Prove $G$ has at most $n^2$ edges.

Tags: graph-theory

If $G$ is a graph on $2n$ vertices that has exactly one perfect matching.

My understanding is to add one more edge and then prove there are two perfect matchings, but it seems hard to prove ...

Comment: I can prove the converse (that there exists a graph with $2n$ vertices and $n^2$ edges and just one perfect matching). :)

Comment: @almagest $n^2$ edges is OK, there can't be $n^2+1$ or more.

Comment: @Abstraction Oh! So you have a proof! Put it up!

Comment: @almagest ...Done.

Comment: The problem statement in the body of the Question should be as complete/self-contained as practical and not dependent on the title for an essential element.  The presentation here asks Readers to piece things together between the title and body, an obstacle that often leads to misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $G=(V,E)$ is a graph on $2n$ vertices with $> n^2$ edges and such that $M\subseteq E$ is a perfect matching.

For every edge $uv\in E\setminus M$ we find an unordered pair of elements of $M$, namely the edge containing $u$ and the (different!) one containing $v$.
As $E\setminus M$ has more than $n^2-n$ elements and there are $n\choose 2$ unordered pairs of elements of $M$, there must be two edges $ab,cd\in M$ that are obtained at least three times.
That is, at least three of the edges $ac,ad,bc,bd$ are in $E$.In alll possible cases, we find a cycle of length $4$ involving $ab$ and $cd$, hence by swapping roles within this cycle obtain a second perfect matching.

Answer (score 2):

1) For $n=1$ the statement is true.

2) Let the statement be true for all $n \le m$ and there be a graph with $2m+2$ vertices and at least $m^2+2m+2$ edges having exactly one perfect matching. Let $A,B$ be two vertices connected by an edge from the matching.

3) There are no more than $2m+1$ edges incident to either $A$ or $B$. More exactly, for any other edge of the matching $CD$, there are no more than $2$ edges connecting $\{A,B\}$ with $\{C,D\}$ (otherwise another matching would exist).

4) Thus, by removing vertices $A, B$ and all incident edges we get a graph with $2m$ vertices, at least $m^2+1$ edges and exactly one perfect matching, which contradicts 2). So, by induction, the statement is true for all $n$.

Comment: @almagest For your example, either $CD$, $CE$ or $DE$ is in the matching. If it is, say, $CE$ then ($AC$, $BE$, $DF$) is also a matching. As said in 3), for ends of any other edge in the matching, there can't be more than $2$ edges connecting $\{A,B\}$ to them.

Comment: +1 Ah, finally got it! The piece I was missing is that the $2m$ other points inherit a perfect matching from that on the $2m+2$ points. So that defines $m$ pairs each joined by an edge. Each of those pairs has at most 2 edges to $\{A,B\}$ hence at most $2m$ in total.